# What happened to Laravel's Eloquent public static function "create" in Model.php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, illuminate-container

In previous versions of Laravel 5.x (I'm not sure when it was changed) I was able to call static method `create` on any Eloquent Model class to insert records into a database.

For example:

```
EloquentUser::create([
    'name' => self::ADMIN_NAME,
    'email' => self::ADMIN_EMAIL,
    'password' => bcrypt(self::ADMIN_PASSWORD),
]);
```

That was calling `public static function create` in **Model.php** (`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`).

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = new static($attributes);

    $model->save();

    return $model;
}
```

In Laravel 5.5 I'm still able to call `create` however **Model.php** is totally rearranged and does not contain this method. What's more important, searching within whole vendor / Illuminate gives me nothing like that. Please explain, how it still works, what it calls behind the scenes.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eloquent's `_call` and `_callStatic` are forwarding calls to an Eloquent Builder instance. The `create` method was moved out of the Model and into the Builder.

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic` -> `__call` -> `newQuery` -> `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder@create`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

[Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L15) uses [QueryBuilder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L19) which uses [EloquentBuilder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L744-L755) where method's code is. Best way for finding particular properties or methods is to use [framework api docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/).